# User values aren't being assigned to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So right now I have my app set up so that a user can create an open game, and then a  player can join this open game and become user2 or player2. This works just find, a player clicks the join button and appear in the lobby database as 'user2'. As shown below

[image]

This is a pretty simple thing, a player makes a game with the user2 equal to null, and then when somebody clicks join they replace null with their user information. This is the code used when a player joins a game.

```
private void joinGame() {
    second = new User(userName, 0, getSide(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
    gm.setUser2(second);
}
```

And then that method is called whenever someone clicks Join. I also have setup a Toast that displays the user2's information by calling

```
gm.getUser2().getUserName();
```

which displays their username, and that works just fine. So I know that when I use the setter `setUser2(second)`, it is working properly

Now to my problem, which doesn't make much sense to me. After somebody joins a game, the Lobby game is deleted and an active game database node is added.

It is added through this code:

```
public static FCGameMaker beginGame;

private void createGame() {
    beginGame = new FCGameMaker(gm.getUser1(), gm.getUser2(), false, false);
    FlipCoinGames.child(userName).setValue(beginGame);
}
```

And this is my FCGameMaker constructor

```
public FCGameMaker(User player1, User player2, boolean gameStarted, boolean gameFinished) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.gameStarted = gameStarted;
    this.gameFinished = gameFinished;
}
```

But when the database is created, player2 does not appear.

This is what the database looks like after the createGame() method is called

[image]

And I have no idea why the second user is not being added, because I am positive that `gm.setUser2(second)` is being called before this createGame() method, so I am not sure why this is not working.

Any help?

```
private FCLobbyMaker gm;

gm = dataSnapshot.getValue(FCLobbyMaker.class);
```

And then my FCGameMaker constructor is already posted, the rest of that class is just getters and setters for the variables.

Comment: You're probably overwriting a new value to that node.

Comment: @jake But whenever the Toast prints, after the game is created, the correct information for user2 appears, so I do not think that that is the case

Comment: Can you please post the code of variable `gm`

Comment: @jake added it to the bottom of the post